# Designing more sophisticated models than simple Db Table models

Tags: php, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I've been using Zend's MVC structure for a while now, but so far my models have been restricted to just reflecting my individual database tables. I'm not sure where to go from here when it comes to writing models to reflect more complicated structures (eg many to many relational database). Does anyone know of any good resources/tutorials (preferably online, but book recommendations appreciated too) on how to approach designing more complex models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're ready for another layer of abstraction. Here's a 3-tier system:

1. Data Layer: actually touches db
2. Business Logic Layer: just operates on data, interchanges to/from 1) and 3)
3. Application / Controller Layer: accepts input, asks Business Logic when doing anything, never touches the "unsanitized" Data Layer directly.

Note that this tiered architecture is aside from the rest of your presentation framework. You should still have a template system and your application layer will implement that; the business and data layers are dealing with data only. This technique centralizes business logic and allows you to swap out other layers with as little effort as possible. (Not meaning easy, but just easy-er.)

See [here](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2004/08/05/dataobjects.html) for a bit of information about extending just a little beyond your current approach. And, see [here](http://www.paragoncorporation.com/ArticleDetail.aspx?ArticleID=21) for a bit of strategy about a business logic layer. They don't talk about a separate data layer, but that's still what I am advising.

To elaborate on the net effect of increased code maintainability, with this system then you could actually change out the db (MySQL to Postgre would still be PAINFUL, but possible) and only need to change one layer of code. Furthermore, this technique is how applications such as PHPBB are able to support multiple database engines, but using as much of the same logic and presentation code as possible. It would also allow you to swap out the UI and create another one that interacts with the business objects which implement all business logic, separate from the controller logic behind a view.

Answer (score 0):

Despite MVC is a very spread development pattern on web, when getting to complex structures as you said we inccur in a design problem named impedance.

Impedance is the overhead that appears when you use different capability models. For example, OOP programming is far less restrictive than plain structures used in databases - you can compose and aggregate objects. For doing that on database, you'll need a N:N relation table.

The current solutions in most frameworks is to use the has_many and belongs_to properties in models. That solves he problem, but the overhead shows up (lots of objects, tons of simple queries...).

It could sound crazy for many developers but: rewrite your models.

Do that for make the composition/aggregation work turns easier. As PHP 5.2+ supports some type casting (objects and arrays), you can use that to write models:

```
<?php
class Photo extends Model {
  private $id;
  private $src;
  private $description;
}

class Employee extends Model {
  private $id
  private $name;
  private $age;
  private Photo $photo;
}

$x = new Employee(123);
echo $x->photo->description;
?>
```